# pass value from one handler to another handler in eclipse e4?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am calculating a value in one handler and I need to pass that value to the other handler. In other words, I have created two menu items in which one menu item(XYZ) calculate values when it is clicked and I need to pass those values so that when the other menu item(ABC) get those values and when **"ABC"** menu item is clicked the value should be displayed in a message dialog box.

Can anyone please suggest me how to do this eclipse rcp e4??

Comment: There are many ways to store this. What does the data belong to? Is it a particular MPart or some data model that you have or something else?

Comment: The data is a set of string values that is stored in a Hashmap. Did I answer your question correctly? I couldnt understand what u meant by "data belong to". Sorry.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to show detached view part when clicking on the menuitem? I can pass the value to the view part using `MPart part = partService.findPart("part id ");`  and set the value from the handler. @greg-449

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

If the menus are both on the same `MPart` you could use `MPart.getTransientData()` which returns a `Map` where you can store temporary data. Or you could use `MPart.getObject()` and store the data in your part object.

If this data needs to be available between parts you could define a class containing the data and store it in the application `IEclipseContext` so that it can be injected where it is required. You can put the data in the context in a life cycle class or by using an AddOn or by using a `ContextFunction`.